# Issue in power portal API call with N:N relationship

Tags: api, many-to-many, entity-relationship, powerapps, powerapps-portal

I have created a new entry in dataverse and made relationship with Account table(N:N). And then set table permission for that new entiry as Global, it works fine.

**But when im changing that table permission to account level the API not working.
**

```
The below error i'm getting in API call for N:N account level permission:
`"{"error":{"code":"9004010D","message":"Common Data Service error occurred.","cdscode":"0x0",
"innererror":{"code":"0x0","message":"Could not find a property named 'many to many relationship name'
```

on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ccm_bid'."}}}" `

Can anyone suggest me the idea to overcome this issue?

Tried in Powe pages application along with portal api.